# How to run a cloud based java program from a website

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

I am building a web app that builds inspection reports. I wrote a java program that builds the report as a Word doc. I want to be able to make a parameterized request to run this program from a website. Essentially, I want the user to be able to "build the report" by clicking a button on the website, which will send a request to the cloud-based java program (along with a "job number" as a parameter so that the program knows what data to fetch to build the report. I have found information on how to make a request from a website but none of the requests seem to handle parameters. How can I do this? I am also open to better solutions to perform this.

Comment: Howdy and welcome to Stackoverflow.   This is a big and open question.  In Google Cloud you can run Java in either a Compute Engine, An App Engine or a Cloud Function.  All of these can receive requests via REST and the REST request can contain parameters needed by your logic.   There isn't a "best" choice for these as there are other factors including scalability, availability, performance and more.  My biggest recommendation is to develop your app locally after having chosen a REST framework (tomcat, WebSphere, plain Java etc etc) and then look to choose a "host".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By following the [Quickstart for Java in the App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/quickstart), I tried to make a simple sample code to get the values of the request parameter.
I cloned the GitHub project and I edited the **HelloServlet.java**, **app.yaml** and **pom.xml** files.

In src/main/appengine/app.yaml, add a service tag and set a name:

```
service: [YOUR_SERVICE_NAME]
```

In src/main/java/com/example/flexible/helloworld/HelloServlet.java, modify:

```
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    out.println(req.getParameter("[YOUR_PARAMETER]"));
  }
```

In pom.xml, add these tags inside `<configuration></configuration>`:

```
<deploy.projectId>[YOUR_PROJECT_ID]</deploy.projectId>
<deploy.version>[YOUR_VERSION]<deploy.version>
```

Then test it locally with this command:

```
mvn clean jetty:run-exploded
```

And deploy it with this one:

```
mvn appengine:deploy
```

Then you can make an http request to

```
http://YOUR_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com?[YOUR_PARAMETER]=[VALUE]
```

> In case the deployment keeps showing the same version, set a lifecycle
> rule in your Cloud Storage, here are the steps to set it up.
>
> 1. Click on the lifecycle of your bucket.
> 2. Click on Add rule Check ‘Newer versions’ and type 1
> 3. Select ‘Delete’
> 4. Click on ‘Save’
>
> Keep in mind that this will delete your previous version.